# Git branch pull messed up

Tags: git

I am relatively new to git so this issue might be my own fault.  But it's too fragile in my humble opinion.  Any advice to revert the damage would be appreciated.

Here is my branch setup.

```
Machine A (Mac):
  master
  couch

Machine B (Windows):
  master
```

On Machine B, I am trying to pull both master and couch branches from Machine A.  Unfortunately, I forgot I haven't created the couch branch on Machine B yet.  Here is what I did on Machine B.  origin is set to Machine A.

```
git pull origin master
git pull origin couch
```

To my surprise, git automatically merge couch branch into master on machine B!  My expectation is for git to create couch branch on machine B for me if it doesn't exist.

How do I undo the merge?  I am not ready to merge couch branch into master yet.  I am going to delete it altogether on Machine B and clone again from Machine A.  I am just curious if there are better solutions.

Comment: Unfortunately, a lack of experience bit you.  Git did exactly what you told it do.  @manojlds is correct in describing what happened, how it should have been done, and what you can do to fix it.  But if you're deleting and recloning, as he said, just do `git checkout -b couch origin/couch`.  That will pull the couch branch down into your local repository.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git pull origin couch`

will fetch the couch branch from Machine A and merge it with the **current branch**, which in your case would have been master and that is why you see couch merged into master. All you had to do was a simple `git pull` and then a `git checkout -b couch origin/couch`

Just do `git reflog`, see where your master was previously and do `git reset --hard <sha from reflog>` or something like `git reset --hard HEAD@{2}`

Or you can do `git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD`